# What is the easiest way to invoke a member function on an argument passed to a mocked function?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Given the interfaces

```
class IFooable {
  virtual void Fooable() = 0;
};

class IFoo {
  virtual void Foo(IFooable* pFooable) = 0;
};
```

and the goole mock mock

```
class TMockFoo : public IFoo {
  MOCK_METHOD1(Foo, void (IFooable*));
};
```

what is the easiest way to specify an action which calls `Fooable()` on the argument to the mocked method `Foo()`?

I have tried

```
TMockFoo MockFoo;
ON_CALL(MockFoo, Foo(_))
  .WithArg<0>(Invoke(&IFooable::Fooable));
```

but this doesn't compile because `Invoke()` with one argument expects a free function, not a member function.

Using `boost::bind` should probably work, but won't necessarily make the code too readable. Before I write a custom `Action`, I wanted to check if I'm not missing something totally obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find an easy way and finally settled with

```
TMockFoo MockFoo;
ON_CALL(MockFoo, Foo(_))
  .WillByDefault(Invoke(boost::mem_fn(&IFooable::Fooable)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot test it as I don't have Google Mock installed, but it seems `Invoke` has another overload with two parameters, the object and the method pointer, so it would be:

```
IFooable* ifooable = new IFooableImpl(...);
TMockFoo MockFoo;
ON_CALL(MockFoo, Foo(_))
  .WithArg<0>(Invoke(&ifooable,&IFooable::Fooable));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to invoke a member function is to use a lambda:

```
   TMockFoo MockFoo;
   ON_CALL(MockFoo, Foo(_))
      .WithArg<0>(Invoke([](IFooable * pFooable) { pFooable->Fooable(); }));
```