# How to invoke a method on a object passed to a mocked method

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am quite new to gmock way of working.

I have a mock with addEvent method which takes object of the type MyClass by a pointer. I need to invoke MyClass::makeCall on this object.

```
class SchedulerMock
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(addEvent, void(MyClass*));

};
```

I found this topic: 
[What is the easiest way to invoke a member function on an argument passed to a mocked function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160600/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-invoke-a-member-function-on-an-argument-passed-to-a-m?rq=1)

And there the example:

```
IFooable* ifooable = new IFooableImpl(...); 
TMockFoo MockFoo;
ON_CALL(MockFoo, Foo(_))
  .WithArg<0>(Invoke(&ifooable,&IFooable::Fooable));
```

But I don't want invoke a method on a object I created in test. I want mock to invoke makeCall on object that is actually passed to a mock.
So I can inject my mock to another class that will create some new objects, and call addEvent on my schedulerMock and I would like this mock to invoke makeCall on a passed argument everytime someone calls addEvent on my mock.
Hopefully I made myself clear.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I took a stab at my understanding of what you want to do... Please let me know by means of small example if I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another function that calls the mock function...

```
class SchedulerMock
{
  public:
    //.... etc
    void addEvent(MyClass* c) const
    {
      c->makeCall();
      mockAddEvent(c); //Wholla, test still works and makeCall called. 
    }

    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(mockAddEvent, void(MyClass*));
};
```

Comment: Hmm thats interesting. I actually had a different idea.
Like adding a function to mock.
void makeCall(MyClass* p) {  p->makeCall();}
and then in expectation do something like this:
EXPECT_CALL(scheduler,addEvent(_)).WillOnce(Invoke(&scheduler, &SchedulerMock::makeCall)); I will try you approach also. Thank you for this hint :)

Comment: This is simple and it works. I often use the pattern to return objects with move semantics (like unique_pointer). Normally I would make addEvent private, but you don't have an interface with a public addEvent (in general a good idea to have derive from an interface for mocking/stubbing purposes, until you know speed is an issue).

Comment: Yes, normally I would mock to an interface, but here I'm trying to mock out a singleton, so my SchedulerMock does not derive from real object, it just have methods with same signatures. Then I need to templetize classes that use this scheduler. I am using so called hi-perf mocking from the google coobook: http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods
The thing is I can't event inherit from this singleton because in his constructor it is invoking another singleton.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a custom Action (in the namespace scope - outside any other functions, tests, etc.). The Action will have access to the arguments of the mocked function call, which in this case is the `MyClass *` you want to call `makeCall` on:

```
ACTION(MakeCall)
{
    // arg0 is predefined as 0-th argument passed to the mock function call,
    //  MyClass* in this case
    arg0->makeCall();
}

TEST(...)
{
    // Create mock object and set expectation, and specify to invoke the 
    //  MakeCall Action
    SchedulerMock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, addEvent(_))
        .WillOnce(MakeCall());

    ...
}
```

When `mock.addEvent(my_class_ptr)` is called, the `MakeCall` action will be invoked with the given `MyClass *` pointer.

You can also use this to pass parameters that are defined in the test to the Action. For example if your `MyClass::makeCall` method took an `int` parameter, let's say, and you wanted to pass two different values the first and second time the method is called:

```
class MyClass
{
    void makeCall(int);
};

ACTION_P(MakeCall, value)
{
    arg0->makeCall(value);
}

TEST(...)
{
    const int FIRST_VAL = 10;
    const int SECOND_VAL = 20;

    MyClass my_class_obj;
    SchedulerMock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, addEvent(_))
        .WillOnce(MakeCall(FIRST_VAL))
        .WillOnce(MakeCall(SECOND_VAL));
    ...
}
```

See the Google mock documentation for more details:

[Google Mock Cheat Sheet - Defining Actions](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#defining-actions)

[Google Mock Cookbook - Writing New Actions Quickly](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#writing-new-actions-quickly)